# Webview doesn't show some characters

Tags: android, webview

I have a utf-8 html page (with proper charset in the HTML) with transcriptions in the text. Some characters in the transcriptions are shown as empty squares. I've tried loading with loadDataWithBaseUrl and a simple loadData. It seems to work on 4.1, but doesn't work in 3.0. Maybe font problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the contents like this?

```
String contents = res.getString(R.string.content_details);
WebView wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", contents, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the html so I can try to load it? Something that happened to me once is that as I work with Eclipse on a Mac. The encoding of the workspace is MacRoman by default; I changed it back to UTF-8 and it solved the problem.